# Javascript & character is removed from the code

Tags: javascript, php, character-encoding

I'm working on a website where the first lines of codes is this:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Then some lines down the HTML starts and in the `<head>` sections there is some javascript code included. A part of the code where it's going wrong is posted below.

```
'com/j.php?a='+account_id+'&u='+encodeURIComponent(d.URL)+'&r='+Math.random());var a=d.creat'
```

Now after the page is loaded, it looks like this (looking at the source).

```
'com/j.php?a='+account_id+'u='+encodeURIComponent(d.URL)+'r='+Math.random());var a=d.creat'
```

The difference is that the `&` characters are removed from the code. And this code now doesn't work.

I think this is caused by the charset `UTF-8`. But I can't remove this. How would I be able to get those & characters in the javascript?

**EDIT**

I tried using `<!CDATA`, the characters are not removed now, but the code still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to replace "&" with "&amp;"?

Comment: Then it pust `&amp;` in de code, which doesn't work in the URL.